# Update column with the sum of another one

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, qsqlquery, postgresql-11

I used PgAdmin4 to develop a PostGIS database. 
I tried to update a column (called "surface_net") in a table called "parcelles" with the sum of another column (called "surface_cultures") in another table called "zones_cultures". The table "zones_cultures" has a foreign key with "parcelles" ("zones_cultures.id_parcelles" = "parcelles.id_egrid").

To sum up, the column "surface_net" is the sum of "zones_cultures" group by the "id_egrid".

So I did this SQL query to update the column "surface_net":

```
UPDATE public.parcelles
    SET surface_net=
    (SELECT sum(zones_cultures.surface_cultures)
        FROM parcelles inner join zones_cultures on parcelles.id_egrid = zones_cultures.id_parcelles
        group by parcelles.id_egrid);
```

But it doesn't work. Here is the result:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Could someone help me with my SQL query to be able to update the column "surface_net"?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause in the subquery that makes it return 1 relevant result for 1 row of the table you're updating. I believe this should work:

```
UPDATE public.parcelles p
    SET surface_net=
    (SELECT sum(zones_cultures.surface_cultures)
        FROM parcelles inner join zones_cultures on parcelles.id_egrid = zones_cultures.id_parcelles
        where parcelles.id_egrid = p.id_egrid
        group by parcelles.id_egrid);
```

Comment: I'm glad it did. Don't forget to upvote and accept if this worked for you.

Comment: Just a last question: do you know how I could create an "auto update" with this code? I want that every time I add new values in the "zones_cultures", the "parcelles" table is update automatically with the update you gave me.

Comment: @SophieCompagnon In general, you can do this in two ways: have `parcelles` be a `view` instead of a table, or by using a `trigger`. Using triggers should usually be avoided because they are a maintenance nightmare. So the best way to handle this is to create a view. If you need more help it would probably be best to create a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

when you applied group by it returned multiple values as a result it thrown error, just remove group by it will work

```
UPDATE public.parcelles
    SET surface_net=
    (SELECT sum(zones_cultures.surface_cultures)
        FROM parcelles inner join zones_cultures on parcelles.id_egrid = zones_cultures.id_parcelles
        );
```

Or if you want to update per id then use below no need group by

```
UPDATE public.parcelles p
    SET p.surface_net=
    (SELECT sum(zones_cultures.surface_cultures)
        FROM parcelles inner join zones_cultures on parcelles.id_egrid = zones_cultures.id_parcelles
        where parcelles.id_egrid = p.id_egrid
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
UPDATE public.parcelles p
    SET surface_net=sum(zones_cultures.surface_cultures)
 inner join zones_cultures where p.id_egrid = zones_cultures.id_parcelles
```